# Button within clickable table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table cell which is clickable and fires a jQuery event when clicked. Within that cell I also have a button, which has another jQuery event when clicked. The issue is, when the button is clicked both the cell and button events are fired.

For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cell').click(function () {
            alert('cell clicked');
        });        
        $('#button').click(function () {
            alert('button clicked');
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell">
            <button id="button">go</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I prevent the cell click event being fired when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` which allow you to stop bubbling of event to the parent dom.

**Example**

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('button clicked');
});
```

set the `table` width to `100%` and test it.

**Test Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('#cell').click(function () {
            alert('cell clicked');
        });        
        $('#button').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert('button clicked');
        });
    });

</script>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="cell">
            <button id="button">go</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Dipesh. All good answers but picked this for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

stop the `event propagation` which is called `event bubbling to the parent`:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('button clicked');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
stopPropagation
```

This example should fix it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cell').click(function () {
        alert('cell clicked');
    });        
    $('#button').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cell').click(function(event){
     if($(event.target).is('#button')){
         event.stopPropagation();
      }    
   });    
});
```